# ASP.NET Master Page and jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a single site.js file which has a

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initMenu();
});
```

and the corresponding MasterPage:

```
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Site.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

In the above example `initMenu()` is required to run on all pages, so naturally the site.js is put in the master page.

However, there are some pages which requires a different set of initialization code so it does not feel to make all pages run the following initialization.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        initMenu();
        showGallery(); <-- Problem?
    });
```

How should i structure the JS references so all pages can share a common initialization and other pages do not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add other `document.ready` event handlers to the pages that need additional ones, for example this can be in the page that needs the gallery setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(showGallery);
</script>
```

...would execute your `showGallery()` function when the DOM is ready.  Also, as long as it appears after your previous code, it's sure to run after it.  `ready` handlers will execute in order (unless called via `.bind("ready"...)` which is different...those happen after, but still in order).

Comment: +1 for being elaborate, and for the terse code. it's obviously the functional equivalent of what i wrote (minus one layer of pointless encapsulation) but yet i never thought to write it like that. neat :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define several functions to be executed at DOMReady. I would simply add the following in `gallery.js` (or wherever `showGallery` might be defined)

```
$(function() {
    showGallery();
});
```